# How can i do multiple routes in aspnetcore razorpages with database values

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

I want to create specific routes with my categories. I have a categories like "laptops, phones, cameras, sound systems etc."

I created page named CategoryDetail for show category details. I want to create route with conventions for each category.
For example;

```
mysite.com/laptops
mysite.com/sound-systems
```

I writed following code.

```
services.AddMvc()
                .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
                {
                    var categories = new[] { "laptops", "sound-systems" };
                    foreach (var category in categories)
                    {
                        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/CategoryDetail", $"/{category}");
                    }
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

This code creating route for each category but i don't accesing category name in the CategoryDetail page.

CategoryDetailPage.cs

```
public class CategoryDetailModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
            string category = ???;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're talking about using database values in route configuration in your title. I don't see it in your code. Did you add the categories array for simplification of your code? How are you calling your database?

Comment: I'm Sorry, My categories are coming from database (I did write database values for this) but in this code i did write as mock (var categories = ...). My problem is related with route creation...

Answer (score 0):

> I created page named CategoryDetail for show category details. I want to create route with conventions for each category. For example;
>
> mysite.com/laptops
>
> mysite.com/sound-systems

Try to use `[BindProperty]` attribute. `[BindProperty]` binds form values and query strings with the same name as the property. `(SupportsGet = true)` is required for binding on GET requests.

Not clear that the design of the page where category is sent from , the following is a working demo ,  you could refer to and make modification as per your need.

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model RazorPages2_2Test.Pages.Peoples.IndexModel

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person[0].Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Person[0].Age)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.Person) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
        </td>
        <td>

            <a asp-page="./PersonDetails" asp-route-Name="@item.Name">PersonDetails</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
```

PersonDetailsModel

```
public class PersonDetailsModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        string name = Name;
    }
}
```

The route obtained by the above code is `/Peoples/PersonDetails?Name=Sherry`，change the route template in the `@page` directive in the .cshtml file to get the route `/Peoples/PersonDetails/Sherry` like below

```
@page "{Name?}"
@model RazorPages2_2Test.Pages.Peoples.PersonDetailsModel
```